# Blinking text cross browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a blinking text.

First I tried the `<blink>` HTML tag, but it is only supported in Mozilla Firefox.

Then I tried CSS:

```
<style>
.blink {text-decoration: blink; }
</style>
```

It's not working on IE 6.

Then I tried javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doBlink() {
  // Blink, Blink, Blink...
  var blink = document.all.tags("BLINK")
  for (var i=0; i < blink.length; i++)
    blink[i].style.visibility = blink[i].style.visibility == "" ? "hidden" : "" 
}

function startBlink() {

  if (document.all)
    setInterval("doBlink()",500)
}
window.onload = startBlink;
</script>
```

Now it's not working on Safari or Chrome.

Can anybody help me use blinking text which will run on all the different popular browsers? (IE 6, Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome Safari, Opera.)

Comment: Just a little note: This was universally considered an extremely bad idea back in the 90s. Everyone but the advertisers hated it.

Comment: You should just pass the function, and not a string to `setInterval`. i.e. `setInterval(doBlink,500)`

Comment: @chris @danjah i know blinking text is bad idea but its demanded by my client.

Comment: And nowadays even Mozilla Firefox dropped support for the `<blink>` element.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative for <blink>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18105152/alternative-for-blink)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This can be achieved with CSS3 like so

```css
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
    from {
        opacity: 1.0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0.0;
    }
}
blink {
    -webkit-animation-name: blink;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1.0, 0, 0, 1.0);
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

It even has a nice fade effect. Works fine in Safari, but Chrome cries a little on the inside.

Comment: Is there any pure CSS way to make it look the old way? (I mean with no transitions - just blinking) The _steps_ treats strange...

Comment: Got it! When I set Keyframes to `0% { opacity: 1.0; } 50% { opacity: 0.0; } 100% { opacity: 1.0; }` and the element's timing function to `steps(1)`, it treats as expected :)

Comment: @arkanciscan: If you copy code from other authors for educational purposes, please provide reference to where you've taken it from. For example with this answer, you probably have not written it your own so in case this is true, please update your answer and provide reference.

Answer (score 11):

The truly cross browser / legacy browser blink tag...

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<blink>ULTIMATE BLINK TAG!</blink>

<!--[if lt IE 10]>
<script>

toggleItem = function(){
    var el = document.getElementsByTagName('blink')[0];
    if (el.style.display === 'block') {
        el.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        el.style.display = 'block';
    }
}

setInterval(toggleItem, 1000);

</script>
<![endif]-->

</html>
```

CSS

```
blink {
  -webkit-animation: blink 1s steps(5, start) infinite;
  -moz-animation:    blink 1s steps(5, start) infinite;
  -o-animation:      blink 1s steps(5, start) infinite; 
  animation:         blink 1s steps(5, start) infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink {
  to { visibility: hidden; }
}
@-moz-keyframes blink {
  to { visibility: hidden; }
}
@-o-keyframes blink {
  to { visibility: hidden; }
}
@keyframes blink {
  to { visibility: hidden; }
}
```

Comment: One seeming consequence of using `visibility` is this use of animation does not seem to work for `:hover` (at least on Firefox 34 on Linux, where it cycles once, perhaps the "hovering" state is not possible for a hidden element and is not re-enabled when the element becomes visible). Using `opacity` seems to be more robust.

Answer (score 4):

```
var el = $(".blink");
setInterval(function() {el.toggle()}, 500);
```

Comment: `setInterval(el.toggle, 500);`

Comment: This is bad because when the element is hidden, the layout will be affected, and the whole page might be moving around.

Answer (score 2):

Simple jquery implementation, feel free to extend to fit your needs http://jsfiddle.net/L69yj/

```
var element = $(".blink");
var shown = true;
setInterval(toggle, 500);

function toggle() {
    if(shown) {
        element.hide();
        shown = false;
    } else {
        element.show();
        shown = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this jQuery

```
function blinks(hide) {
    if (hide === 1) {
        $('.blink').show();
        hide = 0;
    }
    else {
        $('.blink').hide();
        hide = 1;
    }
    setTimeout("blinks("+hide+")", 400);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    blinks(1);
});
```

Note : include the jquery file and give a class name 'blink' on element which you want to blink.

Tip: .show() and .hide() doesn't not reserve the width and height of the element... If you need to hide the element, but not his place (dimentions) at the document, use .css("visibility", "hidden or visible") instead.

Answer (score 1):

**Works in IE 10, Firefox 23.0.1, Google Chrome 29.0, Opera 16.0**

```
blink(0.7);

function blink(speed) {

    if (speed) {
        if (document.getElementsByTagName('blink')) 
            setInterval("blink()", speed*2000);

        return; 
    }

    var blink = document.getElementsByTagName('blink');

    for (var i=0; i<blink.length; i++) {
        blink[i].style.visibility = blink[i].style.visibility == "" ? "hidden" : "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<p id="blink">My name is Ankurji1989</p>


<script type="text/javascript">

var blink_line = document.getElementById("blink");

function d_block(){

    if(blink_line.style.visibility=='hidden')
    {
        blink_line.style.visibility='visible';
    }
    else{
        blink_line.style.visibility='hidden';
    }

}
setInterval(function(){d_block();}, 1000);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is working smoothly in all the browsers...Please try it it will work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function blinker()
    {
        if(document.getElementById("blink"))
        {
            var d = document.getElementById("blink") ;
            d.style.color= (d.style.color=='red'?'white':'red');
            setTimeout('blinker()', 500);
        }
    }
</script>

<body onload="blinker();">
    <div id="blink">Blinking Text</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You should use setTimeout(blinker, 500) instead of setTimeout('blinker()', 500)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
function blinkIt() {
    if (!document.all) return;
    else {
        for(i=0;i<document.all.tags('blink').length;i++){
            s=document.all.tags('blink')[i];
            s.style.visibility=(s.style.visibility=='visible') ?'hidden':'visible';
        }
    }
}
```

You may use a timer instead of using the tag. I have tested this on IE7 and Firefox. Both browsers allow this, however Chrome doesn’t work properly. Hope you got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works great:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function blinker()
    {
        if(document.querySelector("blink"))
        {
            var d = document.querySelector("blink") ;
            d.style.visibility= (d.style.visibility=='hidden'?'visible':'hidden');
            setTimeout('blinker()', 500);
        }
    }
</script>



<body onload="blinker();">
    <blink>Blinking Text</blink>
</body>
```

It looks really like the old version, plus it is used the same too.

Answer (score 0):

This is not my code, but it works well in our web site.
Only problem is that It works if included in the html but not when referenced as a seperate script.

```
    <style>
    #blinker    { color: #58bf7a }
    #blinker.on { color: #58d878 }
    </style> 

    <script> 
        var blinker;
        function blink() {
            blinker.className = blinker.className ? "" : "on";
        }
        window.onload = function() {
            blinker = document.getElementById("blinker");
            var interval_id = setInterval(blink, 1000);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: It also needs a line something like this of course... 
          <li><a href="New.html"><h1 id="blinker"; >What's New?<p ></p></h1></a></li>