# How to make blinking/flashing text with CSS 3

Tags: html, css, css-animations, opacity

Currently, I have this code:

```
@-webkit-keyframes blinker {
  from { opacity: 1.0; }
  to { opacity: 0.0; }
}

.waitingForConnection {
  -webkit-animation-name: blinker;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.5, 0, 1, 1);
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.7s;
}
```

It blinks, but it only blinks in "one direction". I mean, it only fades out, and then it appears back with `opacity: 1.0`, then again fades out, appears again, and so on...

I would like it to fade out, and then "raise" from this fade back again to `opacity: 1.0`. Is that possible?

Comment: No offense, if he wants to blink his text, he wants to blink his text. It doesn't matter what year it is. The most innovative people in the world are those who don't live by rules. Quite the opposite, they usually break them and next, everyone copies them. I guess Apple is a great example. So is Mackie etc etc. I'd feel better if people just keep their opinions for themselves and just answer the question to the point :-)  As said, no offense. Sounds a little harsh but I don't want to provoke not offend anyone. No hard feelings. ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Imitating a blink tag with CSS3 animations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955163/imitating-a-blink-tag-with-css3-animations)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using CSS for fade-in effect on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679567/using-css-for-fade-in-effect-on-page-load)

Answer (score 1011, accepted):

You are first setting `opacity: 1;` and then you are ending it on `0`, so it starts from `0%` and ends on `100%`, so instead just set opacity to `0` at `50%` and the rest will take care of itself.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/umz8t/6490/)

```css
.blink_me {
  animation: blinker 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="blink_me">BLINK ME</div>
```

Here, I am setting the animation duration to be `1 second`, and then I am setting the `timing` to `linear`. That means it will be constant throughout. Last, I am using `infinite`. That means it will go on and on.

> Note: If this doesn't work for you, use browser prefixes like
>   `-webkit`, `-moz` and so on as required for `animation` and
>   `@keyframes`. You can refer to my detailed code [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16344389/7)

---

As commented, this won't work on older versions of Internet Explorer, and for that you need to use jQuery or JavaScript...

```
(function blink() {
  $('.blink_me').fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500, blink);
})();
```

<sup>Thanks to Alnitak for suggesting [a better approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344354/how-to-make-blinking-flashing-text-with-css3/16344389#comment54567328_16344389).</sup>

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/umz8t/6491/) *(Blinker using jQuery)*

Comment: Just noticed that this, applied to one text element, consumes ridiculous amount of CPU on my computer using firefox. Beware.

Comment: please define *"older versions of Internet Explorer"*, it doesn't appear to work in `9`

Comment: @JarrodRoberson You should use sites like http://caniuse.com to check the browser support for the properties am using in this code, I think that is least a user can do by himself.

Comment: best answer for being the most easy to understand solution avialable

Comment: @Alnitak I would appreciate if you explain *bad idea*

Comment: @Mr.Alien there's no synchronisation between the two - the fades will take a bit longer than the timer (and timers aren't reliable anyway) and eventually you'll likely end up with unbounded queue of animations queued up on the element.   The correct approach would be to do without the timer and "recursively" call `blinker` as the completion callback to the `.fadeIn` call.

Comment: @Alnitak makes sense, will update my answer soon. Thanks for explaining. Appreciated.

Comment: @Mr.Alien also the whole thing could just be an IIFE - this one line will do the whole thing including initial invocation:   `(function blink() { $('.blink_me').fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500, blink); })();`

Comment: `step-end` instead of `linear` was what I wanted.

Comment: any ideas on this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67542758/how-to-blink-two-emogies-at-the-same-time-replacing-one-for-another ?

Answer (score 116):

The best way to get a pure "100% on, 100% off" blink, like the old `<blink>` is like this:

```css
.blink {
  animation: blinker 1s step-start infinite;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="blink">BLINK</div>
```

Comment: The only true "blink" solution. And also works with `color` property etc. Other stuff are workarounds or "fade" animations.

Answer (score 83):

Use the **`alternate`** value for [**`animation-direction`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/animation-direction) (and you don't need to add any keframes this way).

> #### `alternate`
>
> The animation should reverse direction each cycle. When playing in reverse, the animation steps are performed backward. In addition, timing functions are also reversed; for example, an ease-in animation is replaced with an ease-out animation when played in reverse. The count to determinate if it is an even or an odd iteration starts at one.

**CSS**:

```
.waitingForConnection {
  animation: blinker 1.7s cubic-bezier(.5, 0, 1, 1) infinite alternate;  
}
@keyframes blinker { to { opacity: 0; } }
```

I've removed the `from` keyframe. If it's missing, it gets generated from the value you've set for the animated property (`opacity` in this case) on the element, or if you haven't set it (and you haven't in this case), from the default value (which is `1` for `opacity`).

And please don't use just the WebKit version. Add the unprefixed one after it as well. If you just want to write less code, use [the shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/animation).

```css
.waitingForConnection {
  animation: blinker 1.7s cubic-bezier(.5, 0, 1, 1) infinite alternate;  
}
@keyframes blinker { to { opacity: 0; } }

.waitingForConnection2 {
  animation: blinker2 0.6s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1) infinite alternate;  
}
@keyframes blinker2 { to { opacity: 0; } }

.waitingForConnection3 {
  animation: blinker3 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;  
}
@keyframes blinker3 { to { opacity: 0; } }
```

```html
<div class="waitingForConnection">X</div>
<div class="waitingForConnection2">Y</div>
<div class="waitingForConnection3">Z</div>
```

Comment: How to make it blink faster? Changing 1.7s messes it up.

Comment: @AlexG you could replace the `cubic-bezier` part with `ease-in-out` or something else: http://cubic-bezier.com/

Comment: +One for cubic-bezier, because all interesting things are non-linear

Answer (score 26):

If you want smooth animations, try this.

```
    .blink {
        animation: blinker 1s infinite;
    }
      
    @keyframes blinker {
        from { opacity: 1.0; }
        50% { opacity: 0.5; }
        to { opacity: 1.0; }
    }
```

```
    <span class="blink">I am blinking</span>
```

Comment: I liked so much the effect!!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 18):

Alternatively if you do not want a gradual transition between show and hide (e.g. a blinking text cursor) you could use something like:

```
/* Also use prefixes with @keyframes and animation to support current browsers */
@keyframes blinker {  
  from { visibility: visible }
  to { visibility: hidden }

  /* Alternatively you can do this:  
  0% { visibility: visible; }
  50% { visibility: hidden; }
  100% { visibility: visible; }
  if you don't want to use `alternate` */
}
.cursor {
  animation: blinker steps(1) 500ms infinite alternate;
}
```

Every `1s` `.cursor` will go from `visible` to `hidden`.

If CSS animation is not supported (e.g. in some versions of Safari) you can fallback to this simple JS interval:

```
(function(){
  var show = 'visible'; // state var toggled by interval
  var time = 500; // milliseconds between each interval

  setInterval(function() {
    // Toggle our visible state on each interval
    show = (show === 'hidden') ? 'visible' : 'hidden';

    // Get the cursor elements
    var cursors = document.getElementsByClassName('cursor');
    // We could do this outside the interval callback,
    // but then it wouldn't be kept in sync with the DOM

    // Loop through the cursor elements and update them to the current state
    for (var i = 0; i < cursors.length; i++) {
      cursors[i].style.visibility = show;
    }
  }, time);
})()
```

This simple JavaScript is actually very fast and in many cases may even be a better default than the CSS. It's worth noting that it is lots of DOM calls that make JS animations slow (e.g. JQuery's $.animate()).

It also has the second advantage that if you add `.cursor` elements later, they will still animate at exactly the same time as other `.cursor`s since the state is shared, this is impossible with CSS as far as I am aware.

Comment: This works well EXCEPT for iOS Safari.  Any ideas how to get it working on Safari?

Comment: @JoeOrost I've included a JS alternative for browsers that don't support CSS animations. In my opinion it may actually be a better solution generally!

Answer (score 17):

```css
@-webkit-keyframes blinker {  
  0% { opacity: 1.0; }
  50% { opacity: 0.0; }
  100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes blinker {  
  0% { opacity: 1.0; }
  50% { opacity: 0.0; }
  100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}

.blink {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  animation: blinker 2s linear infinite;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <i class="blink"></i>
  LIVE
</div>
```

Answer (score 14):

I don't know why but animating only the `visibility` property is not working on any browser.

What you can do is animate the `opacity` property in such a way that the browser doesn't have enough frames to fade in or out the text.

Example:

```css
span {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: blinking 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blinking {
  from,
  49.9% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50%,
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<span>I'm blinking text</span>
```

Comment: This is silly - just use `step-start` (see my answer).

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for. Thumbs Up.

Answer (score 14):

My solution:

```css
.blink {
 animation: blinkMe 2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes blinkMe {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
 50% {
  opacity: 1;
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
}
```

```html
<p class="blink">Blink</p>
```

I use blinkMe for the name of the animation, 2s for the duration, linear for the timing, and infinite so that it repeats forever.

We need to use JavaScript and jQuery for older browsers as they don’t support animation and/or @keyframes:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 window.setInterval(function() {
  $(".blink").fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000);
 }, 2000)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="blink">Blink</p>
```

If you want to make a blink effect that works just like the blink tag, this will work:

```css
.blink {
 animation: blink 0.5s step-start infinite;
}
@keyframes blink {
 0% {
  opacity: 1;
 }
 50% {
  opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 1;
 }
}
```

```html
<p class="blink">Blink</p>
```

Change the durations if you want to adjust the speed.

Answer (score 9):

Change duration and opacity to suit.

```css
.blink_text { 
    -webkit-animation-name: blinker;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-name: blinker;
    -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-name: blinker;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-timing-function: linear; 
    animation-iteration-count: infinite; color: red; 
} 

@-moz-keyframes blinker {
    0% { opacity: 1.0; }
    50% { opacity: 0.3; }
    100% { opacity: 1.0; } 
}

@-webkit-keyframes blinker { 
    0% { opacity: 1.0; }
    50% { opacity: 0.3; }
    100% { opacity: 1.0; } 
} 

@keyframes blinker { 
    0% { opacity: 1.0; } 
    50% { opacity: 0.3; } 
    100% { opacity: 1.0; } 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is good example for everyone. Try it once

```
.blinking_live {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background: #58C03D;
    animation: blink-live 1s cubic-bezier(0, 0.2, 0.8, 1) infinite;
}

@keyframes blink-live{

    0% { opacity: 1.0; }
    50% { opacity: 0.0; }
    100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}


<div class="blinking_live"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Late but wanted to add a new one with more keyframes ... here is an [example on CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OoyPvv) since there was an issue with the built-in code snippets:

```css
.block{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:30px 50px;
  background:#000;
}
.flash-me {
  color:#fff;
  font-size:40px;
  -webkit-animation: flash linear 1.7s infinite;
  animation: flash linear 1.7s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flash {
  0% { opacity: 0; } 
  80% { opacity: 1; color:#fff; } 
  83% { opacity: 0; color:#fff; } 
  86% { opacity: 1; color:#fff;}  
  89% { opacity: 0} 
  92% { opacity: 1; color:#fff;} 
  95% { opacity: 0; color:#fff;}
  100% { opacity: 1; color:#fff;}
}
@keyframes flash {
  0% { opacity: 0; } 
  80% { opacity: 1; color:#fff; } 
  83% { opacity: 0; color:#fff; } 
  86% { opacity: 1; color:#fff;}  
  89% { opacity: 0} 
  92% { opacity: 1; color:#fff;} 
  95% { opacity: 0; color:#fff;}
  100% { opacity: 1; color:#fff;}
}
```

```html
<span class="block">
  <span class="flash-me">Flash Me Hard</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
.neon {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 8px yellow;
  animation: blinker 6s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
@keyframes blinker {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  19% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  21% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  22% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  23% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  36% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  41% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  42% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  43% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

I used `font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;`

This is the import of the font (goes on the top of the style.css)

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@300&display=swap");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
    .class1{
        height:100px;
        line-height:100px;
        color:white;
        font-family:Bauhaus 93;
        padding:25px;
        background-color:#2a9fd4;
        border:outset blue;
        border-radius:25px;
        box-shadow:10px 10px green;
        font-size:45px;
    }
     .class2{
        height:100px;
        line-height:100px;
        color:white;
        font-family:Bauhaus 93;
        padding:25px;
        background-color:green;
        border:outset blue;
        border-radius:25px;
        box-shadow:10px 10px green;
        font-size:65px;
    }
</style>
<script src="jquery-3.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#div1').addClass('class1');
        var flag = true;

        function blink() {
            if(flag)
            {
                $("#div1").addClass('class2');
                flag = false;
            }
            else
            { 
                if ($('#div1').hasClass('class2'))
                    $('#div1').removeClass('class2').addClass('class1');
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        window.setInterval(blink, 1000);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for me by using **class=blink** for the respective element(s)

Simple JS Code

```
// Blink
      setInterval(function()
        {

        setTimeout(function()
        {

        //$(".blink").css("color","rgba(0,0,0,0.1)"); // If you want simply black/white blink of text
        $(".blink").css("visibility","hidden"); // This is for Visibility of the element  


        },900);


        //$(".blink").css("color","rgba(0,0,0,1)");  // If you want simply black/white blink of text
        $(".blink").css("visibility","visible");  // This is for Visibility of the element

        },1000);
```