# javascript, div blinking instead of fading

Tags: javascript, html, fade, blink

I'm making a site that has an area that it's content disappear and re-appears. So when the user clicks certain button, the `<div>`'s content fades out and fades in the content relative to the clicked icon.

First time the function `getabout` is clicked it works OK, but whenever I click on `clear()` and then again on `getabout` it starts blinking. I've discovered that it does the `clean` to the div but it happens that the content re-appears again from nothing and becomes intermittent.

Here is my JavaScript code, it's commented so you could give me a hand here:

```
var check = null; //this will be checking the instance of div's content
const wait_time = 50; //the time it will take to fade

function getabout(id) {
    /*  prevent second call to the same function to bug */
    if (check == id) return;
    var titleOpacity = 0,
        textOpacity = 0;
    /*  this changes the title first    */
    document.getElementById("title").style.opacity = 0;
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "this is the title";
    // recursive call to the opacity changer, it 
    // increases opacity by 0.1 each time until it's 1
    setInterval(function () {
        titleOpacity = fadeIn(titleOpacity, 'title');
    }, wait_time);
    /*  changes the content next to the title   */
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById("dialog").style.opacity = 0;
        document.getElementById("dialog").innerHTML = "this is the content";
        setInterval(function () {
            textOpacity = fadeIn(textOpacity, 'dialog');
        }, wait_time);
    }, 500);
    check = id; // defines the instance "about" at the moment
}

function fadeIn(opacity, id) {
    opacity += 0.1;
    document.getElementById(id).style.opacity = opacity;
    document.getElementById(id).style.MozOpacity = opacity;
    if (opacity >= 1.0) clearInterval(listener);
    return opacity;
}

function clear() {
    var opacity = document.getElementById("title").style.opacity;
    // supposed to decrease the opacity by 0.1 but it's not doing that
    setInterval(function () {
        opacity = fadeout(opacity);
    }, wait_time);
    //cleans the title and dialog to fill with the next button user clicked
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("dialog").innerHTML = "";
}

function fadeout(opacity) {
    opacity -= 0.1;
    document.getElementById("title").style.opacity = opacity;
    document.getElementById("dialog").style.MozOpacity = opacity;
    if (opacity <= 0.0) clearInterval(listener);
    return opacity;
}

function getregister(id) {
    if (check == id) return;
    clear(); // proceed to fade out the content and clean it
    check = id;
}
```

I don't understand what is the error of the code. with the `clear()` function it should smoothly fade out the content and then clean it. But it just cleans the div. And next time I use `getabout()` function, instead of smoothly fade in again as it does the first time, it starts to blink.

I'm relatively new to web programming and I refuse JQuery for now. I want to understand deeply javascript before go to JQuery and this is why I would just like to know pure JavaScript solutions and considerations about this.

Comment: It's because in getabout() you keep setting textOpacity to 0. So it's going from 0, to 0.1, and then back to 0. textOpacity I think is in a different scope inside of the setInterval function()

Comment: Your clearInterval call needs a reference - you have 'listener' in your code but you aren't setting that variable up to reference your timer.  I.e. listener = setInterval(...

Comment: if you would like to have css3 solution than you can refer my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16344389/1542290)

Comment: Sir, "listener" means that is the respective function call that is refered.

Comment: @redconservatory , I don't see how can that part of the code produce that behavior. I'm making a recursive loop to fadeIn that ends when Opacity is grater or equals to 1.0. Perhaps I didn't understand what you meant. Maybe you could elucidate me a little more by being more specific. But I'll be looking to check the code. It's just I'm not getting the logic that why it reproduces that since I made it an end. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive managed to cock up my comment so trying again!

I think your problem is that you're not clearing the setInterval correctly - ensure you use listener = setInterval(...)

As it stands your clearInterval(listener); is doing nothing as 'listener' is not defined.  So your fade out function continues to run.

Comment: But I've tested putting an Alert there from each +0.5 and it just goes two times (when it gets to 0.5 and to 1.0, I presume). Are you sure that that is the problem? Because listener, as fas as I know, refers to the "this" function. But I could be wrong.

Comment: no 'listener' is not a reserved word..  There could be other errors in there btw I've not had a chance to run the code.  Also note that style.opacity=xx in IE terms only works from version 9 onwards but I suspect that's not too much of a concern at the moment!

Comment: Thinking about it, you'd probably be better off with a setTimeout in this case - that way it just fires the once and then you can reset it to fire again if the element's opacity hasn't reached 1 (or 0) yet.  That way you avoid having to set/clearInterval  eg in your fadeIn function, close it with: if (opacity < 1) { setTimeout(..);}

Comment: You are right. I was misunderstanding the point. When I passed trough that documentation I should be very tired and understood that not the way it was supposed to. Thank you very much for your patience and I'm very grateful for your knowhow. Thanks a lot!