# css3 animation, change property after animation starts?

Tags: html, css, web-deployment, css-animations

please see below:

```
    @-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
{


0% { height:200px;     }

50% {opacity:1}

50% {height:300px; opacity: 0; }


}
```

I would like to start fading the object away only 50% thorugh the animation. not at the beginning. This currently doesn't do any opacity animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this i made  some changes in your fiddle it's work  and also link of new fiddle

```
  <div class="blink_me"> Blink</div>

  .blink_me {
     animation-name: blinker;
     animation-duration: 5s;
     animation-iteration-count: infinite;

    -webkit-animation-name: blinker;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    background:#ff0000;
    border:1px solid #00ff00;
 }


 @-webkit-keyframes blinker {
   0% {width:20px; opacity: 0;}  
   50% {width:20px; opacity: 1; }
   100% {width:50px; opacity: 0; }
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/umz8t/293/

Comment: 2 upvotes and a tick? what was wrong with my answer? also, this is just a copy of my answer..

Comment: @Mr.Alien your answer is also right but not as dgamma3 want he like add height property with opacity.

Answer (score 2):

Not getting your question quiet well but I assume you want to delay the start of your animation, if it's that so.. than you can use `animation-delay` property... This will help you in delay your animation by few seconds

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/umz8t/289/) (Modified demo of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16344389/1542290))

```
.blink_me {
    animation-name: blinker;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;

    -webkit-animation-name: blinker;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

    -moz-animation-delay: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
    animation-delay: 5s;
}

@-moz-keyframes blinker {  
    0% { opacity: 1.0; }
    50% { opacity: 0.0; }
    100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blinker {  
    0% { opacity: 1.0; }
    50% { opacity: 0.0; }
    100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}

@keyframes blinker {  
    0% { opacity: 1.0; }
    50% { opacity: 0.0; }
    100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}
```

---

As commented by [jCuber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20258662/is-it-possible-to-change-css-properties-through-an-animation/20258735#comment30218717_20258735), if you want to start animation at `50%` than try this

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/umz8t/290/)

Comment: I believe he wants the opacity to start changing only after 50% through the animation

Comment: @Mr.Alien right that works. but what happens if you have different properties in the mix, not just opacity. e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/umz8t/291/

Comment: @dgamma3 I was using `span` so as its `inline` element it wont take `width` so here you go http://jsfiddle.net/umz8t/294/

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you just made a simple mistake the last line should read 100% not 50%. It could actually read anything between 51% to 100%. You also were missing a semi-colon, added it in.

```
   @-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
{


0% { height:200px; }

50% {opacity:1; }

100% {height:300px; opacity: 0; }


}
```