# Text fade in and out jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an issue. I have two text. On page load when first text fades out i want the second text to fade in same line and the second text should stay. Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/st6rxwjr/1/

Here is my code :

```
<div class="text1 animated  zoomIn">Welcome to our site</div>
<div class="animated text2 bounceIn">Company Name</div>
```

CSS:

```
body { padding-top:30px;}
.text2 {
    display: none;
}
div {
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-align:center;
}
```

JS :

```
function fade() {
    $('.text1').fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut();
    $('.text2').delay(2000).fadeIn();
}
    fade();
```

Comment: Why not make with pure CSS? I've provided a simple jQuery solution as well http://stackoverflow.com/q/16344354/1542290

Comment: The problem is IE 8 support :) Jquery will work in IE 8 and CSS 3 will work in IE 9. I had to create a intro text for a client so i found this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need like: [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/st6rxwjr/2/)

Change in your Jquery code text2 delay. You given 2000 So text2 will appear before text1 will disappear.

```
function fade() {
        $('.text1').fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut();
        $('.text2').delay(2500).fadeIn();

}
    fade();
```

Comment: Ohh It was an issue with time!!

Answer (score 1):

Try using call back function like this:

```
function fade() {
    $('.text1').fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut(1000,function(){
        $('.text2').delay(2000).fadeIn();
    });
}
```

You can put 0 instead of 1000 if you don't want any slow fade In effect.