# Jqgrid text blink based on condition in colmodel

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am fetching record from databases in some action some col model value change in some click at the time i need to differentiate that col-model changed so now the text have to blink .for example there are 5 row and 3 had change in col model and rest not  change .i loaded the jQgrid now i tried in load-complete but no luck as beginner i do no kindly help on this ??

```
loadComplete: function(data) {
$.each(data.rows,function(i,item)
{
alert("data======>"+JSON.stringify(i)+"  "+data.rows[i].change);
if(data.rows[i].change ==Y)
{

}
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use `rowattr` or `cellattr` to set CSS class on the row or on cells which makes blinking. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16344389/315935) about blinking, [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10531680/315935) about the usage of `rowattr` and [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12180842/315935) about the usage of `cellattr`.