# Shiny - Detect a change in input with a warning in Ui.R

Tags: r, shiny

I have an app that has many inputs and that uses an `actionButton()` to do some calculation that takes a non trivial amount of time including reading some files and plotting a map.

During some user testing, some of the feedback that the need to re-press the `actionButton()` after adjusting an input was non intuitive. I would like to render a warning message (read "helpful reminder") that users need re-press the `actionButton()`. I'd like it if this message only rendered after inputs are changed since the last press of the `actionButton()`.

So far I have tried using global variables inside an 'eventReactive()' and trying to use `identical()`  with no luck.

**My question is:** How can I render a helpful reminder to re-press an `actionButton()` when any inputs have changed since last time the button was pressed?.

Here is a minimal example of an app with many inputs that takes some time to output something

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    #arbritray inputs
    sliderInput("in1", label = "Input 1", value=1,min=0,max=5),
    sliderInput("in2", label = "Input 2", value=2,min=0,max=5),
    sliderInput("in3", label = "Input 3", value=3,min=0,max=5),
    actionButton("StartCalculation","Calculate")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    textOutput("answer")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  out <- eventReactive(input$StartCalculation,{
        Sys.sleep(2) #simulate long computation
    input$in1+input$in2+input$in3
  })

  output$answer <- renderText({
    out()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37470226/blinking-loading-text-in-r-shiny

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `reactiveVal` inside your server to save the "status" (changed or unchanged). Just make sure that the status gets updated whenever either the button is pressed or inputs change.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- fluidPage(
  inputPanel(
    #arbritray inputs
    sliderInput("in1", label = "Input 1", value=1,min=0,max=5),
    sliderInput("in2", label = "Input 2", value=2,min=0,max=5),
    sliderInput("in3", label = "Input 3", value=3,min=0,max=5),
    actionButton("StartCalculation","Calculate")
  ),
  textOutput("answer"),
  textOutput("status")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  status <- reactiveVal()

  out <- eventReactive(input$StartCalculation,{
    status("up to date")
    Sys.sleep(2) #simulate long computation
    input$in1+input$in2+input$in3
  })

  observeEvent({list(input$in1,input$in2,input$in3)},
               {status("Needs recalculation")})

  output$answer <- renderText({out()})

  output$status <- renderText({status()})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Perfect, a really nice solution! (sorry for the delay in replying)