# Make blinking text in textareainput in r shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am using the css and code below:

```
 tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
   textArea {
     background-color: #58d68d !important;
     border: none;
   }')))
```

and

```
textAreaInput(
          "inputId",
          "Select Working Directoy Path :- ",
          value = HTML("Processing"),
          width = NULL,
          height = '40px',
          cols = NULL,
          rows = NULL,
          placeholder = " Eg :- C:/Users/paras118053/Desktop/OFAC Soluton Design",
          resize = NULL
        )
```

I want to make the text "Processing" blink. I am able to achieve the below output using this code:

[image]

How can I make it blink?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37470226/blinking-loading-text-in-r-shiny) is helpful?

Answer (score 0):

This is more a CSS question than Shiny, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344354/how-to-make-blinking-flashing-text-with-css-3) stackoverflow question.

[How to make blinking/flashing text with CSS 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344354/how-to-make-blinking-flashing-text-with-css-3)