# Blinking text in a button

Tags: javascript

I have this function to blink text in a button "AddMoney" :-

```
 function blinker1(){
    document.getElementById("AddMoney").value="Add Money";
    setTimeout("document.getElementById('AddMoney').value='                   '", 500);
    xxxx = setTimeout("blinker1()",1500);
                     }
```

And I stop it and set the text with this function:-

```
    function cease1() {   
            clearTimeout(xxxx);
            document.getElementById("AddMoney").value="Add Money";
                      }
```

It works but now and again there is no text in the button.
Anyone Know why and how to fix.

Comment: Try to put xxxx outside the function

Comment: xxxx is a global variable if that is what you mean.

Comment: when are you exactly losing the button text

Comment: Button text flashes and when I call cease1 the flashing stops and the text appears in button. Now and again there is no text in button. An alert after the cease1 call shows the text is always set but sometimes it doesn't show in the button.

Comment: I don't get the meaning of now and again. Are you sure the text isn't getting clipped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now and again there is no text in the button. Anyone Know why?

It happens whenever `cease1()` is called while `setTimeout("document.getElementById('AddMoney').value='                   '",500)` is still scheduled, which happens on average every third time. In that case, the `blinker1()` timeout is cancelled and the content is shown, but shortly after it will be hidden again.

> … and how to fix?

You'll have to cancel both timeouts:

```
var timerA, timerB;
function blinker() {
    document.getElementById("AddMoney").value = "Add Money";
    timerA = setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('AddMoney').value = "";
    }, 500);
    timerB = setTimeout(blinker1, 1500);
}
function cease1() {   
    clearTimeout(timerA);
    clearTimeout(timerB);
    document.getElementById("AddMoney").value = "Add Money";
}
```

Alternatively, use two functions that are mutually scheduling each other so that only one timer is active at a time:

```
var timer;
function blinkerA() {
    document.getElementById("AddMoney").value = "Add Money";
    timer = setTimeout(blinkerB, 500);
}
function blinkerB() {
    document.getElementById('AddMoney').value = "";
    timer = setTimeout(blinkerA, 1000);
}
function cease1() {   
    clearTimeout(timer);
    document.getElementById("AddMoney").value = "Add Money";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This version should work a bit better for you. I stuck with vanilla Javascript rather the introducing jQuery:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8mwxgpkb/1/)

```
var blink = window.setInterval(blinker1, 900)

function blinker1() {
  var addMoney = document.getElementById("addMoney");

  addMoney.innerHTML = " ";
  setTimeout(function(){addMoney.innerHTML = "ADD MONEY"}, 300);
}

document.getElementById('stop').addEventListener('click', function(){
    clearInterval(blink);
})
```

Note - it would be better and easier to achieve a blink effect [using pure CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344354/how-to-make-blinking-flashing-text-with-css3).

Comment: You should use `clearInterval` instead of `clearTimeout`, even when both work.

Comment: Good catch. Updated!

Answer (score 1):

The text disappears because you only set clearTimeout on `xxxx`, so the timeout for `setTimeout("document.getElementById('AddMoney').value='                   '", 500);` will always execute. I think this is the reason why there is no text in the button.

My approach would be to set a counter, let say the text need to blink 10 times (based on your code it will take 15sec.)  Each time when the text shown the counter will decrease until it reaches 0.

sample code (https://jsfiddle.net/2trodftu/1/)

```
    //counter
    var blinkCounter = 10;

    // blink method
    function blink() {
        document.getElementById("AddMoney").value="Add Money";

        if (blinkCounter > 0) {
            setTimeout("document.getElementById('AddMoney').value='                   '", 500);
            setTimeout(blink,1500);
        }

        blinkCounter = blinkCounter - 1;
    }

    //initializer
    blink();
```

Hope  this helps.