# How to create "Blinking" text with CSS only?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to create a CSS only solution for blinking text. The text should say:

Researching...

and I'd like it to fade-in and fade-out, giving the impression to the user that it's researching at the same pace that a beating heart.

This is the code that I have so far:

**HTML**:

```
<p class="blinking">Researching...</p>
```

**CSS**:

```
.blinking {
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out infinite;
  opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes opacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 0.5
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

But this isn't working, also this is for a chrome extenson, so as long as it works in the latest version of chrome should be enough.

Comment: replace `transition` with `animation`

Comment: Replace transition with animation, and you can also add alternate if you want https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1864/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your issue is that you use transition and animation in 1 line.

Change your `transition` to `animation` like below. Also changed the opacity to 1 -> 0 -> 1 instead of 1 -> 0.5 -> 0 because you want to have a blink not 1 -> 0 and than no transition to 1 opacity again.

A fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kc6936cw/

```
.blinking {

    animation: opacity 2s ease-in-out infinite;
    opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes opacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 0
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

**Edit:** jtmingus comment could also be used:
*You could also add the `alternate` tag to the end instead of going from 1 -> 0 -> 1. That would look like `animation: opacity 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;`*

Comment: Awesome!! This was it. I'll accept your answer as soon as SO lets me.

Comment: You could also add the `alternate` tag to the end instead of going from 1 -> 0 -> 1. That would look like `animation: opacity 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;`

Answer (score 4):

This shoud do it

```css
.blinking {
    animation: mymove 2s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes mymove {
    from {opacity:0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<p class="blinking">Researching...</p>
```

this is a much smoother animation

Answer (score 1):

```
.blinking {
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out infinite;
    animation: blinker 1s linear infinite;
  opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 0.5
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

There is already a very good example
[How to make blinking/flashing text with css3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344354/how-to-make-blinking-flashing-text-with-css3)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, instead of `transition`, `animation` should be used.

```
.blinking {
  animation-name:animate;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 0.5
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```