# How can I make my last point blinking in highstock?

Tags: highcharts

I want to make last point blinking in high-stock. But there is no feature for that.

Can I do it by java-script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you could achieve this is to assign a custom class to your last point, and do some CSS for that point to make it blink.

Assigning a custom class to a point can be done like this

```
series: [{
  data: [29.9, 71.5, {y: 54.4, className: 'customClass'}],
}]
```

Here, the last point as been assigned to with the class `customClass`. Then we use some CSS magic taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16344389/8376046). And we get a blinking last point:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, {y: 54.4, className: 'customClass'}],
        marker: {
         radius: 10
        }
    }]
});
```

```css
.customClass {
  animation: blinker 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 250px"></div>
```

**JSFiddle example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/jr2x64t8/9/

Comment: excuse me, my chart is real time and I have to add points with addPoint() function.
how can I add className with addPoint() ?