# How to translate this css in withStyle / jss ready syntax

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I'm trying to make some element blink in css, under React/material-ui, using withStyle.

The syntax from this post looks nice:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48320520/9316077

```
.blink {
  animation: blinker 1s step-start infinite;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

I simply tried the following:

```
    '@keyframes blinker': {
      '50%': {
        opacity: 0,
      },
    },

    '& .blink': {
      animation: '$blinker 1s step-start infinite',
    },
```

Adding the `$` before `blinker`based on this issue:
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/13793

But this crashes my webpage. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyframes name is generated [since JSS core v10](https://github.com/cssinjs/jss/blob/master/changelog.md#1000-alpha1-2018-12-26) so depending on which version you are using you need to use $ when you are referencing a scoped name or without when name/id is global.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I see in my npm package-lock that I have jss version 10.4.0, so this should be ok. Does my syntax look ok? I am not sure about the `50%` part....