# How to flip two emojis indefinitely using css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a text with two emojis 
I want to flip one emogi with another using css.

When the first emogi is shown I want to the second emoji to be hidden. So they kinda indefinitely replacing each other.

I found here a great example how to make text [blink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344354/how-to-make-blinking-flashing-text-with-css-3)

```css
    .blink {
      animation: blinker 1s step-start infinite;
    }
    
    @keyframes blinker {
      50% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
```

```html
    
    <div class="blink"></div>
```

So how would you show the second emogi while the first one is hidden?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a pseudo-element:

```css
.blink::before {
  content: "";
  animation: blinker 1s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  0% {
    content: "";
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    content: "";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="blink"></div>
```

Comment: is there anyway to add a simple transition in between ?

Answer (score 2):

```css
.emoji-cont {
  position: relative;
}

.blink, .blink-2 {
    position: absolute;
}

.blink {
  animation: blinker 1s infinite;
}

.blink-2 {
  animation: blinker 1s .5s infinite;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="emoji-cont">
  <div class="blink"></div>
  <div class="blink-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there anyway to add a simple transition in between ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the pseudo-element `display: inline-block`, to open up more animation options.

Here we use `transform: scaleX()` to create a flip effect, as if the emoji has different sides (front and back).

Useful if you're were looking for a different way to transition between the two emojis; rather than a simple fade.

```css
.blink::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  animation: blinker 1s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  0% {
    content: "";
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
  100% {
    content: "";
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="blink"></div>
```