# How to display Flash Message on every click jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on ajax and php,I am fetching data from database successfully,But
ajax response showing in html for first time only, But i want to show "success/error" message
on every click

Here is my html/view code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Mybtn').click(function(){
        $('#MyForm').toggle(500);
  });
});
</script>

<button id="Mybtn" class="btn btn-primary">Message</button>
<div id="result"></div>
<form id="MyForm" action="" method="post">
    <label>Enter wallet address</label>
    <input type="text" name="wallet" id="wallet"  placeholder="Enter wallet address"/><br>
    <label>Enter your msg</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="senderwallet" id="senderwallet" value="332121212121212121" >
    <input type="text" name="msg" id="msg" placeholder="Enter your msg"/><br>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<script>
$(function(){
   $('#submit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
            var wallet = $('#wallet').val();
            var msg = $('#msg').val();
            var senderwallet = $('#senderwallet').val();
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url('main/SednMsg'); ?>",
            data: {wallet:wallet,msg:msg,senderwallet:senderwallet},
            success: function(data){
                 $('#result').html(data); 
                  $('#result').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
                }
        });
});
});
</script>
```

Here is my code in controller,how can i get "success" or "error" message on every click? Where i am wrong ?

```
function SednMsg()
{
    $wallet=$_POST['wallet'];
    $msg=$_POST['msg'];
    $senderwallet=$_POST['senderwallet'];
    $result['data'] = $this->M_main->SaveMsgs($wallet,$msg,$senderwallet);
    if($result['data']=="1") {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
            <strong>Success!</strong>
            </div>';    
    } else {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
            <strong>error!</strong>
            </div>';    
    }   
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344354/how-to-make-blinking-flashing-text-with-css-3

Comment: Do you call that function anywhere?

Comment: @lino I dont think that is a Duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show your element again if you call it second time.

```
<script>
$(function(){
   $('#submit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
            var wallet = $('#wallet').val();
            var msg = $('#msg').val();
            var senderwallet = $('#senderwallet').val();
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url('main/SednMsg'); ?>",
            data: {wallet:wallet,msg:msg,senderwallet:senderwallet},
            success: function(data){
                 $('#result').html(data); 
                  **$('#result').show(); // added this line**
                  $('#result').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
                }
        });
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: working for me, Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a class with css animation instead of JavaScript setInterval or setTimeout