# Is there a HTML function/command that makes text inside it blink?

Tags: html, web

I just wanted to know if there is a HTML function/command that makes the text blink for my website.

Thanks!

Comment: Literally [`<blink>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blink), but it's deprecated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344354/how-to-make-blinking-flashing-text-with-css-3