# I'm having trouble in Dreamweaver's CSS code. How can I attach two values to one property and have both work for any browser?

Tags: css

I'm trying to get my text to be underlined while blinking, but when I follow suggestions from other questions, it still only lets one value work.

I tried

```
text-decoration: underline;
#text-decoration:blink;
}
```

I tried

```
text-decoration: underline, blink
```

And nothing worked. How can I get the text to blink while underlined? I'm trying everything I can find, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Check the syntax of the examples you posted.

Comment: As in what? What's wrong with the syntax? I'm new and in Digital Media 1, but my teacher doesn't know how to have 2 values, either.

Comment: You can recreate `blink` using [CSS animations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955163/imitating-a-blink-tag-with-css3-animations), although you almost certainly shouldn't.

Comment: Why? What would happen?

Comment: Your users would hate you for using it at all.

Comment: Your first example `text-decoration: underline;
#text-decoration:blink;
}` is invalid. It should be more like `#someID {text-decoration: underline;}`. And text-decoration doesn't even have a blink value.

Answer (score 1):

Seperated multiple CSS property values with a space:

```
p {
    text-decoration: blink underline;
}
```

Note from [W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#lining-striking-props):

> Conforming user agents may simply not blink the text.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. If you define same property several times in a CSS statement, only the last one is used.

And `underline` and `blink` are values of the same `text-decoration-line` property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-line

Using the hacks will only change behaviour in **different browsers**. For example, set `#text-decoration: blink` for IE6 (I suppose) and `text-decoration: underline;` for all other browsers.

Comment: Ok, but I tried them on one line and it didn't work.

Comment: It doesn't matter if they are on one lines or not. Only the last rule will be used. In your case it's `text-decoration: underline;` as most of browsers wouldn't parse the `#text-decoration:blink;` rule because of syntax error.