# Blinking text on database changes

Tags: mongodb, meteor, collections

I'm working on a small application that has a message window. The messages are stored in a db and updated by fetching 5 of the latest messages:

```
scienceTeamMessages = new Meteor.Collection('scienceTeamMessages');

Meteor.methods({
    'sendMessageFromMS': function(message, destination) {

        if (destination === "scienceTeam") {
            scienceTeamMessages.insert({
                message: message,
                createdAt: new Date()
            });
        }
    }
});
```

These messages are then iterated over in an html template:

```
{{#each messages}}
    <li><h6>{{message}}</h6></li>
{{/each}}
```

What I would like, and I can't figure out how to do, is for the latest message to blink a few times, so as to draw attention from the user when a new message arrives. Like, fading in and out from black to red 3 times.

Any suggestions? I know how to do the css, but I am unsure about how to do it on changes to the database. That is why the other solutions on SO won't work in this specific question.

Comment: this isn't a duplicate since it's a meteor specific question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the animations have a look at the link posted in the comments: [Imitating a blink tag with CSS3 animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955163/imitating-a-blink-tag-with-css3-animations)

If you'd like to add animations for a specific time limit use Meteor.setTimeout().

To do animations in Meteor see this Microscope demo example: https://github.com/DiscoverMeteor/Microscope/blob/master/client/templates/application/layout.js

And lastly, if you'd like to perform a certain action when an element is added to a collection, consider using `cursor.observe` or `cursor.observeChanges` which is documented here: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe

A lot of links, but hopefully with all that together you can put together the solution you're looking for.

Comment: Seems like enough information here for me to figure out something!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set this logic on your helper :

```
Template.foo.helpers({
    messages: function() {
      var elements = scienceTeamMessages.find({},{sort: {created_at: -1}}).fetch();
      for (var i = elements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        elements[i].drawAttention = (i == 0);
      };
      return elements;
    },
})

<template name="foo">
  {{#each messages}}
    <li><h6 {{#if drawAttention}}class="burn-yours-eyes"{{/if}}>{{message}}</h6></li>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

I did not tested this code, hope it will help you.