# D3.js Warning: Unresponsive Script Message

Tags: javascript, d3.js, warnings, blink

I'm getting an error message after a while, when using a blink function in D3

```
.transition()
                                .duration(250)
                                .delay( 0)
                                .each(blink);
```

---

```
function blink() {

                        var line = d3.select(this);
                        (function repeat() {
                        line = line.transition()
                        .style("opacity", function(d) { return(1);})
                        .transition()
                        .style("opacity", function(d) { return(0);})
                        .each("end", repeat);})();
            }
```

[image]

Comment: what is your error ?

Comment: are you running this in browser ? Could you set up a JSFiddle with the bare amount of code to show us your problem. Also when you put .style("opacity",function(d){return(1);{), you can just put .style("opacity",1). Also, maybe put a slight delay after the transition, otherwise your browser may get over cluttered

Comment: You've created a nested transition, every 17ms, you are **creating** another transition which in turn fires every 17ms....  What are you really trying to do here, just blink a line every 250ms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment:

> You've created a nested transition, every 17ms, you are creating another transition which in turn fires every 17ms...

To fix this, remove the nesting:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      
      var svg = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', 300)
        .attr('height', 300);
        
      svg
        .append('line')
        .attr('y1', 150)
        .attr('y2', 150)
        .attr('x1', 0)
        .attr('x2', 300)
        .style('fill', 'none')
        .style('stroke', 'steelblue');
        
      svg.selectAll("line")
        .each(blink);
        
      function blink(){
        var self = d3.select(this);
        self
          .transition()
          .duration(250)
          .style("opacity", function(d) { 
            return self.style("opacity") === "1" ? "0" : "1";
          })
          .each("end", blink);
      }
      
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Of course, if you just want something to blink you can do this [with straight css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955163/imitating-a-blink-tag-with-css3-animations):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
    <style>
.blink {
  animation: blink-animation 1s steps(5, start) infinite;
  -webkit-animation: blink-animation 1s steps(5, start) infinite;
}
@keyframes blink-animation {
  to {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink-animation {
  to {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
    </style>
    
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      
      var svg = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', 300)
        .attr('height', 300);
        
      svg
        .append('line')
        .attr('class', 'blink')
        .attr('y1', 150)
        .attr('y2', 150)
        .attr('x1', 0)
        .attr('x2', 300)
        .style('fill', 'none')
        .style('stroke', 'steelblue');       

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you very much, I hope this will fix my problem

Comment: I have something like this 

    setInterval(vmhvlan,30000);
   

function vmhvlan() {var svg = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', 300)
        .attr('height', 300);
        
      svg
        .append('line')
        .attr('y1', 150)
        .attr('y2', 150)
        .attr('x1', 0)
        .attr('x2', 300)
        .style('fill', 'none')
        .style('stroke', 'steelblue');
        
      svg.selectAll("line")
        .each(blink);} 

function blink(){
    ....
      } could this be the problem?

Comment: @DeGoya, you still get an unresponsive message?  Why are you re-appending a new svg, line, etc... every 30s?

Comment: because my data changes consistently and I have to make a connection every 30 seconds to my server to get the updated Data. In the beginning of the method, I have something like this "d3.select('#content').html("");" and then I re-appending every DOM element. I have the feeling, that for every new generated blink call, the old one is still running, although the old one isn't existing anymore.

Comment: @DeGoya, tough to answer without being able to reproduce it.  When you say `although the old one isn't existing anymore` do you `.remove()` from the SVG?  Make sure you cancel any transitions on it before you remove.  **And** don't remove with a transition.  `svg.selectAll('line').transition().remove()` is **bad**, `svg.selectAll('line').transition(); svg.selectAll('line').remove(); `

Comment: @DeGoya, I let [this example run](http://plnkr.co/edit/mjTvkZQipUsofXUcmOpC?p=preview) for a good long while and haven't seen any issues.

Comment: your example has the same problem as mine, it hangs for me. I remove everything like this d3.select('#body').html("");

Comment: @DeGoya, you are correct.  I didn't let it run long enough to see the issue.  The memory usage is ever increasing.  How about [this version](http://plnkr.co/edit/cVaCTgdmxTWO5HZEZZVG?p=preview); the memory usage stays flat.