# blinking gif with javascript - timer

Tags: javascript, timer

i have a div-container with a gif-picture. I want to blinking this gif, but the gif is only show and is not blinking

```
  function blink() {
      time2 = time2 - 1;
      if (time2 >= 0) {
          var ani = setInterval(blinkerle() {
              if (document.getElementById(risiko1).style.visibility == "visible") {
                  document.getElementById(risiko1).style.visibility = "hidden";
              } else {
                  document.getElementById(risiko1).style.visibility = "visible";
              }
          }, 1000);

      }
  }
```

the function is called via `blink();`

from another place. thanks for your help

Comment: Have you taken a look at the console? There's an error message waiting for you.

Comment: `setInterval(blinkerle(){ ` what's this? :\

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this with pure CSS:

```css
div {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url("http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png");
  background-position: top left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-indent: -999em;
}
/** the blink css is below this comment: **/
.blink {
  animation: blink-animation 1s steps(5, start) infinite;
  -webkit-animation: blink-animation 1s steps(5, start) infinite;
}
@keyframes blink-animation {
  to {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink-animation {
  to {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="blink"></div>
```

[CSS taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16012979/4567375).

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the function keyword in front of the blinkerle() function. It should be:

```
 var ani = setInterval(function blinkerle(){
```

Or preferably use an anonymous function:

```
 var ani = setInterval(function() {
```