# Alternate blinking with CSS3 animation

Tags: css

I am trying to find a CSS-only way to make specific tags (like `p` or `img`) blink in alternating patterns. While I have been able to find a means to make anything blink (see `.blinky`) in code sample, I have not been able to make two separate classes alternate the blinking.

Part of the solution might be the `animation-delay` property shown in `.blinky2`, but after the specified delay in seconds, it blinks in sync with `.blinky` and not offset by the delay.

I found some related SO links that got me started -- [Imitating a blink tag with CSS3 animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955163/imitating-a-blink-tag-with-css3-animations) and [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/) -- but I have not yet seen any instructions to define offset blinking for `.blink2`. Is such a thing supported, or does it require further tricks?

```css
.blinky {
  animation: blink-animation 1s steps(5, start) infinite;
  -webkit-animation: blink-animation 1s steps(5, start) infinite;
  font-size: x-large;
  color: blue;
  display: inline;
}

.blinky2 {
  /* Need make this alternate blinking*/
  animation: blink-animation 1s steps(5, start) infinite;
  -webkit-animation: blink-animation 1s steps(5, start) infinite;
  /* This just postpones blinking for 1-sec, then it's in sync with .blinky*/
  animation-delay: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  font-size: x-large;
  color: red;
  display: inline;
}

@keyframes blink-animation {
  to {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink-animation {
  to {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>The <var>blinky</var> and <var>blinky2</var> classes should alternate blinking.</p>

<div>
  <p class="blinky">Blinky</p>
  <p class="blinky2">Blinky 2</p>
  <p class="blinky">Blinky</p>
  <p class="blinky2">Blinky 2</p>
  <p class="blinky">Blinky</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to alternating blinking lies in setting up the `animation-delay` value to half of the "1s" in `animation: blink-animation 1s steps(5, start) infinite` to "0.5s".

I'm not sure what a generalized formula would look like, but for this purpose "0.5s" seems to work.

I tested this by letting it run for 10 minutes, and still remained blinking in alternation.

So `.blinky2` now looks like this:

```
.blinky2 {
  /* Need make this alternate blinking*/
  animation: blink-animation 1s steps(5, start) infinite;
  -webkit-animation: blink-animation 1s steps(5, start) infinite;

  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
  font-size: x-large;
  color: red;
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use keyframes to get the effect you're after.

What I've done below is define two different animations, `blink-animation` and `alt-blink-animation`. `blink-animation` gets applied to `p` tags, and `alt-blink-animation` gets applied to `div` tags.

`blink-animation` starts with the element hidden, and `alt-blink-animation` starts with the element visible. Simply alternating the keyframes so `blink-animation` is visible while `alt-blink-animation` is hidden and vice versa produces an alternating blinking effect.

```
<p>First blink</p>

<div>Alt Blinking</div>


<style>
  p{
    animation: blink-animation 1s infinite;
  }

  div{
    animation: alt-blink-animation 1s infinite;
  }

  @keyframes blink-animation {
    0% { opacity: 0;}
    100% { opacity: 1;}
  }

  @keyframes alt-blink-animation {
    0% { opacity: 1;}
    100% { opacity: 0;}
  }

</style>
```

Comment: So close. At first, it blinked alternately. But when I left it blinking and came back to the desk, it was blinking in sync.

Comment: How long did it take to see it sync up, and which browser are you using? I've left this running in FireFox for probably five minutes and it's still alternating. Wondering if I'm missing something, or if syncing is browser related.

Comment: It could be browser. I'm using Chrome and writing for a work environment that exclusively uses Chrome.

Comment: Been running the same code in Chrome for a couple of hours and it's still alternating. Weird. Is your blinking pattern more complicated than the example? Or is there more relevant code that might be contributing to the difference?

Comment: I kept it all text to keep it simple, but in reality, `.blinky2` is blinking a div containing an image.