# Flash element with alpine js

Tags: javascript, css, alpine.js

Is there an easy way to flash an element with a background color with alpine? So an example would be to transition from tailwind `bg-red-500` to `bg-transparent` over 2 seconds right when the element is loaded. Thank you!

Comment: Wha not plain css animation?

Comment: I just looked into that as well. Someone said it's not possible with tailwind, but it seems like it is with some config and custom classes.

Comment: And you cant add custom css files for your blinking animation? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13955165/5781499 Feel free to adapt it to your needings

Comment: I wanted to see if I could get it done with tailwind and I could with some config. Well, it's basically custom css at that point. Thanks! :)

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question, so you help other people with the same problem.