# How to blink text in UIWebView in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, cocos2d-iphone

I am working on UIWebView. But blink tag is not working in webview. How to blink text in UIWebView

```
 NSString *htmlText= @"<blink><br>My Text</blink>";

[webView loadHTMLString:htmlText baseURL:nil];
```

Reply ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<blink>` tag is deprecated and shouldn't be used in modern HTML. You can achieve the same effect through JavaScript or pure CSS, which a `UIWebView` will support. This question - [Blinking text cross browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894488/blinking-text-cross-browser) - will help you implement either approach.

Comment: Thanks txt. how to use javascript in my project. can you send me script. Thanks

Comment: You can embed the JavaScript inside your HTML - it doesn't need to be a separate file. The question I linked to should help you out.