# alternative to blink() method

Tags: javascript, html

I am in a need of having a blinking function in my application. Basically, I am creating a calculator and I need something like "|" to blink after the user inputs each numbers from the button. For firefox and opera, something like:

```
var str = "Hello world!";
document.write(str.blink());
```

This is exactly what I want. My problem is they don't work in Chrome, IE or safari. Is there any easy substitution for this or I have to create blinking functionality myself if I want my application to run on cross-browsers?

Comment: @JoeEnos : haha, that is true but don't you think you need it sometime: I am not making the text to blink here. I am just adding a string to the text which blinks to show. Blink is needed in calculator right, It really looks cool!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894488/blinking-text-cross-browser

Comment: Crikey - JavaScript strings have a `blink` method in Firefox?

Comment: Dear lord, it's true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this-:SOLUTION NO 1**

You can create your own custom blink function.This can also be done by creating css class and adding them to our element.

```
function blink()
    {
        setInterval(function () {
            document.getElementById("blink").style.webkitTransitionDuration = "0.7s";
            document.getElementById("blink").style.opacity = 0;
            setTimeout(function () {
                document.getElementById("blink").style.webkitTransitionDuration = "0.7s";
                document.getElementById("blink").style.opacity = 1;
            }, 700);
        },1400);

    }
```

OR

**try this-->SOLUTION NO.2**

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function blink()
        {       
document.getElementById('blink').className = "animated blink_css";
        }
```

**In css**

```
.animated {
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:both;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode:both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode:both;
    animation-fill-mode:both;
    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
    -moz-animation-duration:1s;
    -ms-animation-duration:1s;
    -o-animation-duration:1s;
    animation-duration:1s;
}

  @keyframes 'blink' {
   0% { background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5); }
   50% { background: rgba(255,0,0,0); }
   100% { background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5); 
}
//try moz for mozilla,o for opera and webkit for safari and chrome 
    .blink_css {
        -webkit-animation-name: blink;
        -moz-animation-name: blink;
        -o-animation-name: blink;
        animation-name: blink;
    }
```

*Both of them will work.Tested!!!*

Comment: can I know the Reason?
Bcoz I have used this function and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: as I mentioned,you can create class in css and then apply it to element.

Comment: Your `setInterval` isn't closed properly, and you have `,1400);` at the end which isn't correct.  Any JS parser will tell you this.

Comment: And it does not have any parse errors ,I have tested it ,It works perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes, now it validates ;)

Comment: @Axel:you should have said that in first comment itself.Anyways thanks

Answer (score 4):

you could use just css3 :

```
@keyframes 'blink' {
   0% { background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5); }
   50% { background: rgba(255,0,0,0); }
   100% { background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5); }
}
```

Comment: And then possibly `blink {-webkit-animation: blink 2s;}`, and `document.write('<blink>Hello world!</blink>')` (or equivalent JavaScript that actually writes it into the current document).

Answer (score 1):

If you truly want cross-browser compatibility, you should use a library, jQuery for instance.

Here is a nice little script that accomplishes what you want- http://www.silverphp.com/simple-jquery-blink-script-alternative-to-html-blink-tag.html

On the other hand, if you prefer vanilla JS, you may have to implement it yourself. Maybe use `setInterval()` with a function that makes the element disappear?