# How to change the duration of a CSS3 keyframes-animation with raw JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations

Is there a way to change the duration of a CSS3 keyframes animation with JavaScript? In CSS you can do that with the animation-duration property:

```
animation-duration: 1s;
```

The JavaScript should be raw, i don't want to include jQuery or other JS librarys into my site.

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: @MESSIAH I'm creating a CSS animation library with a simlpe JS framework which attaches the animations to events.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can assign css classes in javascript and put your transition/duration/animation in those css classes Or you can assign your css directly in javascript.

```
document.getElementById('your_id').style.animationDuration="1s";
```

*for cross browsers we can use o,moz,ms and webkit as prefix.*

Example-:

```
 document.getElementById('your_id').style.webkitTransitionDuration="1s";
```

[EXAMPLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679660/alternative-to-blink-method/17679849#17679849)

```
function blink()
        {       
document.getElementById('blink').className = "animated blink_css";
        }
```

// In css

```
.animated {
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:both;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode:both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode:both;
    animation-fill-mode:both;
    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
    -moz-animation-duration:1s;
    -ms-animation-duration:1s;
    -o-animation-duration:1s;
    animation-duration:1s;
}

  @keyframes 'blink' {
   0% { background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5); }
   50% { background: rgba(255,0,0,0); }
   100% { background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5); 
}
//try moz for mozilla,o for opera and webkit for safari and chrome 
    .blink_css {
        -webkit-animation-name: blink;
        -moz-animation-name: blink;
        -o-animation-name: blink;
        animation-name: blink;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this works for me in Chrome. To read the value, you have to use ```window.getComputedStyle```